# How to scanning files and assign values to a 2D array in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I'm a new learner to java and I'm scanning a .dat file and I want to print it out as a table in blueJ. My codes are as follows:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File ("test01.dat")); 
for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++){
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
        int temp = 0;
        temp = sc.nextInt();
        tri[r][c] = temp;
        System.out.print(tri[r][c]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
    sc.nextLine();
}
```

I almost get there but my problem is that my result printed out is 19 numbers including a zero at the end.(It was supposed to be 18 numbers with no zero at the end)
How can I get rid of that zero?
Oh and in addition, my input is just a column of 18 numbers and I'm changing it to a table with 6 rows and 3 columns.
For more information, here is the link of my file: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B6E07F4C7635D773!4577&authkey=!AL9Zw4b4CWlS630&ithint=file%2cdat
Thanks for all the comments and finally I found what I need~(^o^)~

Comment: How do you declare `tri` - remember, arrays in Java are zero indexed, that is, they start at `0` not `1`

Comment: I declare it as: int[][] tri = new tri [6][3]

Comment: How is the data organized in your file? How many lines?

Comment: 18 lines, in each line there is only an int

Comment: @MadProgrammer well, I know arrays are zero indexed, but when creation and declaration the numbers are actually the length of each dimensions.

Comment: Please give us sample test01.dat.

Comment: @Melody When I run your code against a file with 18 lines, each with a number on it, I get the table format you are expecting, along with a `java.util.NoSuchElementException` at the end.  I expect that your extra 0 is a BlueJ artifact.  Try commenting out `sc.nextLine();` and your program should work as intended.

Comment: @Melody But you didn't provide the declaration of the array, so it raised the question, this is why providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem will result in less confusion and better responses ;)

Comment: [link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B6E07F4C7635D773!4577&authkey=!AL9Zw4b4CWlS630&ithint=file%2cdat) This is my file test01.dat. see if you can download it. And I'm using BlueJ for programming.

Comment: @azurefrog well, whether I comment out    sc.nextLine();    the zero still exists. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is using sc.nextLine after sc.nextInt.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File ("test01.dat")); 
for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++){
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++){
        int temp = 0;
        temp = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine().trim());
        tri[r][c] = temp;
        System.out.print(tri[r][c]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This should fix it !
**Note you file should have one integer per line.**

Comment: Your change will **not** produce the desired result, unless you assume that OP's file has *double* "end of line" character(s).

Comment: @azurefrog I changed my code to not make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided StackFlowed is correct. Just comment out "sc.nextLine()" in outer for loop. It'll make you skip one number after every row.